# delete record from database in listview in vb

Tags: database, vb.net, listview

I have a problem. In the properties of listview which is checkboxes = "True". Using this checkbox, I want to delete the data in listview and in the database.

Below is the code:

```
If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to DELETE this record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then

        MsgBox("Operation cancel", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Information")

    End If

    dbSource = "Data Source=LAILATUL-PC\SERVER;Initial Catalog=HotelManagementSystem;Integrated Security=True"


    Dim sql As String = "DELETE FROM [Room] WHERE Room_Code =  @code"


    Using con = New SqlConnection(dbSource)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
            con.Open()

            For Each lvItem As ListViewItem In ListViewRoom.Items
                If lvItem.Checked Then


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", ColumnRoomCode.Text)

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    lvItem.Remove()

                End If
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
```

Using above code, only the data in listview is deleted. The data in the database not deleted.

The interface for listviewitem:

[image]

Thank you if you all can help me. :)

Answer (score 2):

A Command should be executed to have any effect on the database. You need to add this

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

in every loop.

Also the connection could be opened just before entering the loop and should be closed afterward. (Using Statement is recommended here)

Said that, please take a look on Parameterized queries because your code is open to Sql Injections and parsing problems. Also the sql command to delete a record doesn't need a list of fields after the FROM table part.

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

    dbSource = "Data Source=LAILATUL-PC\SERVER;Initial Catalog=HotelManagementSystem;Integrated Security=True"

    ' Parameterized query 
    Dim sql As String = "DELETE FROM [Room] WHERE Room_Code =  @code"

    ' Using statement to ensure proper closing and disposing 
    ' of the objects SqlConnection and SqlCommand
    using con = New SqlConnection(dbSource)
    using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        con.Open()
        ' Add a parameter just one time before the loop with an empty string
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", "")
        For Each lvItem As ListViewItem In ListViewRoom.Items
            If lvItem.Checked Then
                ' Set the parameter value with the value extracted from the ListViewItem
                Dim RoomCode = lvItem.Text
                cmd.Parameters("@code").Value =  RoomCode
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                lvItem.Remove()
            End If
        Next
    End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

One last note. The ColumnRoomCode textbox (?) is always the same, so calling delete one time is enough, but I suppose that this should be changed with some value extrated by you current ListViewItem

Comment: ColumnRoomCode is the column has a checkboxes in the listview not the textbox. i try above code. but the result is still same. after reload the apps, the previous data deleted not delete in the database.tq

Comment: So, where do you have the RoomCode to be passed at the DELETE WHERE clause?. You need it to be able to delete the row checked.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what ur mean

Comment: To delete a single record (the one that correspond to the checked item) you need to instructs the database how to find that record in the table Room. This is the value that you need to pass for the parameter @code. It should be a value that uniquely identifies the record in the table (I was supposing that ColumnRoomCode is that value. If it is not, then how do you identify the record to be deleted?)

Comment: yes right, the ColumnRoomCode is the value to instruct the database find the record in a table room.

Comment: may i know, what the exactly code for delete function in listview?

Comment: Can you add to your question the code that initializes the ListView. It is important to see the values used to set each ListViewItem. Accessing the SubItem in the ListViewItem that contains the RoomCode is the key

Comment: It seems that you have the RoomCode directly in the ListViewItem and not in the subitems. So you need to read the value from lvItem.Text. Updating the answer

Comment: tq so much for helping me :)